# I need help writing a default value with FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I'm trying to use Linq to do something clean in my code, and I have a question about FirstOrDefault.

My code :

```
    private Congé _SelectedCongesN;
    public Congé SelectedCongesN
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedCongesN;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedCongesN)
            {
                _SelectedCongesN = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCongesN));
            }
        }
    } 

    SelectedCongesN = ListeCongés.Where(x => x.Debut <= DateTime.Today && x.Fin >= DateTime.Today).FirstOrDefault();
    CongesN = $"Du {SelectedCongesN.Debut.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")} au {SelectedCongesN.Fin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}";
```

I retrieve in my list, a contract compared to the date of the day.

What I would like is that IF there is no contract to date, I simply retrieve the most recent one (so the first one in the list).

So I added this code below:

```
                    if (SelectedCongesN == null)
                    {
                        if (ListeCongés != null)
                        {
                            SelectedCongesN = ListeCongés.FirstOrDefault();
                        }
                    }
```

If SelectedCongesN is empty (so if the previous FirstOrDefault didn't recover anything), I would like it to take just the last one.

It doesn't work, when I run it doesn't reach this part of the code when SelectedCongesN is null.

So my question is what is the way in my linq request to get my contract back on today's date (which works) and in the opposite case to take the most recent one?

Comment: What data type is `SelectedCongesN`? Is it a struct or a class?

Comment: edited, sorry for the miss

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is `Congé` a class or a struct?

Comment: Why are you don't use `OrderByDescending`?? And, are you sure ListeConges is not null??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` allows to put condition inside it, so no need to use `Where()` in that case.
Also you can use null coalescing operator to simplify your code.

I would do something like that:

```
 SelectedCongesN = ListeCongés.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Debut <= DateTime.Today && x.Fin >= DateTime.Today) ?? ListeCongés.FirstOrDefault();
```

I suppose that ListeCongés is not null anyways

Comment: How is this different to the code in the OP's question (other than the use of `??` rather than an explicit null check)?